# "Self-managing" class in Python : Good practice?

Tags: python, class, pyglet

I have this main function where I instantiate an object from the class `GameWindow(pyglet.window.Window)` (inherited from the pyglet.window.Window() class).

Then, inside the `__init__()` method of that object, I set an interval for repeatedly calling its `update()` method.

**So here's the question** : is the code below a good practice? Is it a good idea to "start" a classe's routine just by instantiating it? Despite the PyLint warning of "variable is declared but never used"?

If no, is there a better (or simply a right) way to do it?

```
# main.py

import pyglet
from game_window import GameWindow

def main():
    window = GameWindow()
    pyglet.app.run()

    # some other code...


# game_window.py

import pyglet

class GameWindow(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__():
        self.__WIDTH = 700
        self.__HEIGHT = 700
        self.__CAPTION = "This is a window"
        super.__init__(self.__WIDTH, self.__HEIGHT, self.__CAPTION)

        self.__FRAME_RATE = 1/120
        pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(self.update, self.__FRAME_RATE)

    def update(delta_time):
        # do whatever it needs to self-manage itself, check conditions, etc.
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with it - but you might want to add an explicit `dispose` method to stop the intervals. Cleaning up will likely be important (especially if it were for objects on the scene rather than the window). I would suggest extracting the scheduling to make mocking (and therefore testing) easier though.

Comment: What are you meaning by extracting the scheduling? I'm not quite expert at that... :/

Comment: All I mean is put the part where you schedule the interval into a new method on the class.

Comment: Ooh okok good idea!